# Qt - Where is the mysql driver in Qt 5.12.6?

Tags: mysql, qt

I started to notice that after version 5.12.3 none more came with the plugin driver, I can't find any information about removing the plugin, I also tried to compile it through this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1TbNjJSlX8, but to my surprise I didn't have the source for the sql module in the source files

Comment: download the source code from https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/5.12.6

Comment: @eyllanesc I downloaded it through the maintenance tool

Comment: So what's your problem? I recommend you find someone to help you write your questions since you seem to have problems with the language since you have confused "font" with "source"

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, google translate

Comment: The source code is in the Qt sources, under qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I managed to compile the code, but only the moc and obj files were generated, what is missing to generate the driver dll?